# Persist array store in session symfony

Tags: arrays, symfony

It's been several days since I've been blocking to persist items from an order into session to database.

I stock articles in session in an array and I do not know how to persist the array. I try to convert the array into an object, I can not. This is my service:

```
 public function addArticle($id)
{

    $sessionCart = $this->session;

    $article = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->find($id);

    $cart = $sessionCart->get('cart');

    $cart[] = $article;

    $sessionCart->set('cart', $cart);

    // use later for delivery
    $sessionCart->get('commande');

    return $sessionCart;
}

public function panier()
{

    $articles = $this->session->get('cart');

    return $articles;
}


public function delivery(Request $request)
{

    $commande = new Commande();

    $articles = $this->session->get('cart');

    $form = $this->form->create(CommandeType::class, $commande);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid())
    {

        $data = $form->getData();

        $this->session->set('commande', $data);

        $response = new RedirectResponse('payment');
        $response->send();
    }

    return [$form, $articles];
}


public function payment(Request $request)
{

    $articles = $this->session->get('cart');
    $commande = $this->session->get('commande');

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

    $em =   $this->doctrine;

    $em->persist($articles);
    $em->persist($commande);

    $em->flush();
    }

    return[$articles, $commande];
}
```

Error : "EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given."

The order is persisted but not the items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand these two lines

```
$cart = $sessionCart->get('cart');
$cart[] = $article;
$sessionCart->set('cart', $cart);
```

$cart is an array and should be an entity isn't it ?

The persist is waiting for an entity, 
maybe you can persist in a foreach loop:

```
foreach($articles as $article){
    $em->persist($article);
}
```

or use a doctrineCollection instead of an array

Comment: Yes $cart is an array that contains the list of article of the order.  It does not work with the foreach.

Comment: if article is a doctrine entity it should work. what is the error message ? what do you see if you `var_dump($article);` at the first line of the foreach ? do you see doctrineEntity ?

Comment: If I do a var_dump nothing appears, I still have the symfony error: EntityManager # persist () expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.